# wrap JScrollPane to TextArea in Java (working with GridBagConstraints)

Tags: java, swing

i new to java and swing (came from c#) and try to add scrollbar to my textarea with no success.
I tried all kinds of techniques ,  it is very difficult to me 
please take a look on the following code, I would be very happy

```
package firmwareUpdate;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class firmwareUpdate {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new firmwareUpdate().createUI();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }



    private void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        //natural height, maximum width
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


        // row #1
        JButton btnUpload = new JButton("Browse hex/bin file...");

        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpload, c);

        JLabel  lblFileName = new JLabel("aaa");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblFileName, c);

        // row #2
        JButton btnConfig = new JButton("Config");
       // c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       // c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
       // c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnConfig, c);

        JButton btnHex2Bin = new JButton("hex2bin");
      //  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      //  c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
       // c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnHex2Bin, c);

        JButton btnFirmwareUpdate = new JButton("Firmware Update");
      //  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       // c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
       // c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnFirmwareUpdate, c);

        JButton btnFirmwareUpdateStop = new JButton("Firmware Update Stop");
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       // c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        //c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnFirmwareUpdateStop, c);


        // row #3
        JButton btnCheckSum = new JButton("Check Checksum");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      //  c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCheckSum, c);

        JButton btnStartBootloader = new JButton("Start Bootloader");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       // c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStartBootloader, c);

        JButton btnStartApplication = new JButton("Start Application");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      //  c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStartApplication, c);


       JTextArea txtFileContent = new JTextArea(30,68);      

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START; //bottom of space
        c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
        c.gridx = 0;       //aligned with button 2
        c.gridy = 4;       //third row
        c.gridwidth = 4;   //4 columns wide
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtFileContent, c);
       //txtFileContent.setVisible(false);

      //////////////  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtFileContent);
       /////////////// scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

       // middlePanel.add(scrollPane);

       // scrollPane.setBounds(10,60,780,500);
        //scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       ////////////////// frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);  

        txtFileContent.setLineWrap(true);
        txtFileContent.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrolltxt = new JScrollPane();
        scrolltxt.setViewportView(txtFileContent);
        scrolltxt.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrolltxt, c);


        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/fwup.png")).getImage());


        frame.setTitle("Firmware Update");
        //frame.setSize(600,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try This

```
JTextArea txtFileContent = new JTextArea(30,68); 
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtFileContent);
frame.add(scroll);
```

Comment: i try this. its not work, it gives a tiny scroll in the top of the frame (outside the textbox)

Comment: What do you want then !!!!! you can additionally set the horizontal and vertical scroll bar policy if required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this will solve your problem, but have you considered that not setting any column widths or heights in your layout may be your concern (line 30 of the code)? Allow me to give you an example:

```
GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();

layout.columnWidths=new int[] {198, 198};
layout.rowHeights=new int[] {70};
panel.setLayout(layout);
```

Wherein, panel is a panel that is pushed onto the JFrame.
NB: I am personally against using the built-in content pane of a JFrame, because of its tendancies to default out on the user; however, for all intents and purposes, it shouldn't be a problem if done right.
I hope this helps, and best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code, the scroll bar for the JTextArea shows up as expected when you exceed the row count of the initial JTextArea (The default value for the scrollbars' visibility are only to be shown when needed: [JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) under verticalScrollBarPolicy and horizontalScrollBarPolicy). If you are asking to have it default as visible, then use either setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(...) or setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(...) on your JScrollPane variable. There are several options available for [ScrollPaneConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ScrollPaneConstants.html)